# Baseball on Mars

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Searching for the title of a short story about kids playing baseball on Mars. Probably Asimov's or DAW World's Best. They could  only play 2 innings because the ball would travel so far, they'd get a home run almost every at-bat. It was really funny!

Comment: Fun fact: Isaac Asimov's surname was originally Azimov. He changed it after a numerologist advised him that changing the "Z" to an "S" would improve his fortunes.

Comment: @Moriarty I'll bite - what's the source of this fun fact? It doesn't sound remotely plausible...

Comment: @user888379 what's that emoticon for "tongue in cheek" again?

Comment: Asimov used to be Azimov is true.  But it was changed while he was very young when the family moved to the US. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov#Family_name_etymology).

Comment: @user888379 just my little joke https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spell_My_Name_with_an_S

Comment: @user888379 Spot on. I read your first comment and thought I read a short story about that exact same thing, and then you gave the link to it! You made me smile a bit more today. Thanks

Comment: @JayV Actually Moriarty provided the link - I've probably read the story, but I clearly didn't remember it...

Comment: oh no, I have forgotten how to read...

Comment: @Moriarty Spot on. I read your first comment and thought I read a short story about that exact same thing, and then you gave the link to it! You made me smile a bit more today. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

This is [Arthur Sternbach Brings the Curveball to Mars](https://www.baen.com/Chapters/9781625791443/9781625791443___3.htm) by Kim Stanley Robinson.

> English wasn’t his first language, either. It was Armenian, or
>   Moravian, something like that. Something no one else spoke, anyway,
>   except for an elderly couple in his co-op. So he mumbled what passes
>   for English on Mars, and sometimes even used a translation box, but
>   basically tried never to be in a situation where he had to speak. And
>   made error after error. We must have made quite a sight—me about
>   waist-high to him, and both of us letting grounders pass through us
>   like we were a magic show. Or else knocking them down and chasing them
>   around, then winging them past the first baseman. We very seldom made
>   an out. It would have been conspicuous except everyone else was the
>   same way. Baseball on Mars was a high-scoring game.
>
> But beautiful anyway. It was like a dream, really. First of all the
>   horizon, when you’re on a flat plain like Argyre, is only three miles
>   away rather than six. It’s very noticeable to a Terran eye. Then their
>   diamonds have just over normal-sized infields, but the outfields have
>   to be huge. At my team’s ballpark it was nine hundred feet to dead
>   center, seven hundred down the lines. Standing at the plate the
>   outfield fence was like a little green line off in the distance, under
>   a purple sky, pretty near the horizon itself—what I’m telling you is
>   that the baseball diamond about covered the entire visible world. It
>   was so great.

It was the title story in Asimov's Science Fiction: v23n08 (1999 08)

[image]

Comment: Wow, you guys have good memory. I used to collect Asimov's and DAW Year's Best for years and these were some of my favorite stories. Now I can go back and re-visit them again and reccommend to my friends Thanks so much.

Comment: @Eni - Don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as "accepted" (by clicking the little tick to the left of the answer) to show that it's the right one.